# Greatest Lower Bounded Irrational?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, bounded-variation

If all elements of $S$ are irrational and bounded from below by $\sqrt 2$ then $\inf S$ must be irrational .

I would say this statement is true since $S=\{ \sqrt 2, \sqrt 3, \sqrt 5,\ldots\}$ the greatest lower bound is $\sqrt 2$ which is irrational and bounded from below the sequence.

Is this correct?

Comment: You've found an example that says it *can* be true for *one* cases. You haven't yet proven or disproven whether it *must* be true for *all* cases.

Answer (score 3):

HINT: All elements of $S=[2,3]\setminus\Bbb Q$ are irrational and bounded below by $\sqrt2$, but $\inf S>\sqrt2$; what is $\inf S$?

Answer (score 2):

Consider $$S = \left\{2 + \frac{\sqrt{2}}{n} : n = 1, 2, 3, \dots\right\}$$

Then every element of $S$ is larger than $\sqrt{2}$, $S$ contains no rational entries, and $\inf S = 2$ is rational.

Comment: I'm confused why is 2 the Greatest lower bound, if the first term is 2+√2/n.

Comment: oohh i get it √2/n goes to 0 and 2 would be the lowest value. Right?

Comment: @remedy Yes: The term that's being added gets as small as you like, so the infimum is $2$.